# Validator bound with "this" shows FromGroup as undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a very basic sign-up form where I use a FormGroup to manage my FormControls. I have a custom validator that checks that my passwords and its confirmation match. To do so I used the: `this.foo.bind(this)`
However, when loading the page the first time the validator runs (as expected) but the `this` (that shows the right object in the debugger) has the two injected dependencies but nothing else. Therefore, it gives me an error saying that my formGroup doesn't exist.

Declaration:

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
public formGroup = new FormGroup({
    nameController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    emailController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    passwordController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.notForbiddenPassword]),
    passwordConfirmController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.passwordConfirmationMatchValidator.bind(this)])
  });
```

validator:

```
passwordConfirmationMatchValidator(confirmation: AbstractControl) {
    return (this.formGroup['passwordController'].value === confirmation.value) ? null : {'passwordDontMatch': true};
  }
```

Here is a screenshot of Chrome's debugger 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Edited again, I have added a more complete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving what you want to do.

1) Writing a custom validator using [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl).
On your component.ts,

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
    nameController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    emailController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    passwordController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    passwordConfirmController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  }, {
    validator: PasswordValidation.passwordConfirmationMatchValidator
  });
```

Then, write a separate class for your validator. You can access value of the various controls in your form group by using `AbstractControl.get().value`

```
class PasswordValidation {

  static passwordConfirmationMatchValidator(AC: AbstractControl) {
    //console.log(confirmation.get('passwordController').value)
    // do the rest here
    let password = AC.get('passwordController').value;
    let confirmPassword = AC.get('passwordConfirmController').value;
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      AC.get('passwordConfirmController').setErrors({ MatchPassword: true })
    } else {
      return null
    }

  }

}
```

2) Alternatively, you can write your custom validator with only the binded `this`.

On your component.ts,

```
public formGroup = new FormGroup({
    nameController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    emailController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    passwordController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.notForbiddenPassword]),
    passwordConfirmController: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.passwordConfirmationMatchValidator.bind(this)])
  });


passwordConfirmationMatchValidator(formControl: FormControl) {
    // const passwordConfirm = formControl.value;
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

Comment: Although I did use `bind(this)` In my original post. I'll try your fix and come back to you on whether it fixed it or not. In the meantime, I'm just very curious about this behaviour...

Comment: Ok, so there are two ways of writing that validator. I have provided one of them, as stated above, and it does not require the use of `this`, as the values of the form are obtained from the `AbstractControl`. The second way of doing it requires you to make use of `this`. I will post both methods for your reference!

Comment: Cheers! Hmm..Can I see what is written on your validator method?